# Kubernetes delete pods matching name

Tags: kubernetes

I would like from time to time delete all my pods or replicaset to have a clean reboot of my services.

For example on my cluster I have

- service-1 (deployment)
- service-2 (deployment)
- app-1 (deployment)
- app-2 (deployment)

Each deployment have a replicaset and each replicaset have one or more pods.

I want to for example remove all my replicaset beginning by `service` so they will be able to start again from the deployment

I know that I can list all my rs or pods doing

```
kubectl get rs | grep service
```

or

```
kubectl get pods | grep service
```

I do not really know if this is better to remove all pods or rs, I always have some olds rs, I do not really know if they are useful

I want to find a command to restart all my pods or services beginning with `service` for example

Comment: Deleting a pod shouldn't be problem as the deployment controller would bring it back up.

Comment: if u have a deployment, you can use that itself to restart all ur pods

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! any idea about a command I can run to restart all services ?

Answer (score 3):

to recreate the pods of your deployment use command: `kubectl rollout restart ${RESOURCENAME}` where resourcename is the name of the deployment